# My Terminal won’t run my Rscript. Keep getting output of “>quote"

Tags: r, shell, terminal, rscript

I am trying to run an `Rscript from my terminal to check that I made my code properly for class. Whenever I run my` Rscript` using the command :

```
Rscript --vanilla -e ‘source(“file.R”)’ -e ‘print()’
```

I get the output of just

```
quote>
```

I checked my code and my file and I should at least get something. When I run in RStudio my code produces something.
Do you know what I can do to fix this? or any can suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is in the "file.R" script? What OS are you using? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Try a simple script with like 1 line of code and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: R doesn't like "fancy quotes", try changing `“file.R”` to `"file.R"` (notice the difference in quotation marks).